# Dynamical and programmatical mounting a s3 bucket to a windows ec2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Any suggestion on how one would go about dynamical and programmatical mounting a s3 bucket to a windows ec2 instance ? My idea was to code a little server that sits on the windows machine and exposes a rest API endpoint that I can call to do this via FUSE / s3fs.

Does anyone know about any other solutions for that that might exist already ?
I looked threw the AWS API SDK's but nothing seems to fit.

Edit:
rclone.org/rc could be of use :)

Thanks.

Comment: `s3fs` is for linux only, isn't it?

Comment: https://rclone.org/rc/ could be of use

Comment: Windows has a FUSE emulation layer libfuse/WinFsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is rClone, Windows has a FUSE emulation layer libfuse/WinFsp.